# problem when running apt-get update

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-10.04

I'm on an ubuntu server (ec2) , I'm running sudo apt-get update and get the following error :

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-ec2/ec2-tools/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Foun

how ever my /etc/apt/sources.list doesn't contain the ppa.launchpad.net reference .

How can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its not in `/etc/apt/sources.list` try looking in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: Great.  Since you're new here, please click on the check mark on the top left hand side of my answer, if my response solved the problem for you.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ direcotory:

```
grep ubuntu-on-ec2 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Then delete or comment line in list files.